# How can I use the same CreateView and ModelForm to deal with staff privileges?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, create-view

I want to allow all users to create a "Domain" where they are the owner but I'd also like admin users to be able to create a "Domain" for other users.

Here's what I have so far to deal with the non-admin case:

```
# views.py
class DomainCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, DomainActionMixin, CreateView):
    model = Domain
    action = "created"
    form_class = DomainForm
    success_url = 'domains/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(DomainCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

# forms.py
class DomainForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Domain
        fields = ('title', 'url')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('title', placeholder="title"),
            Field('url', placeholder="url"),
        )
        super(DomainForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that I'm using a few mixins and crispy forms so that's why it's a bit non standard. I imagine neither should affect this question.

Answer (score 1):

Define two forms, one for regular users, and one for superusers, which has an extra `user` field.

Then override the [`get_form_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_class) method, that returns the correct form class based on the user's permissions. You can access the user as `self.request.user`, as you have done in the `form_valid` method.

Finally, change your `form_valid` method so that you only set the user for reqular users.

Comment: Thanks - that's a pretty clean and simple solution. Is it not possible to do it using a single form or is that just a bad idea and brings unnecessary complexity?

Comment: It's possible to do this with a single form - if I needed to do it that way, I would leave the owner field in the model form, then in the view's `get` and `post` I would check self.request.user, and if not superuser set `form.fields['owner'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()`, pass in the request user as the initial value, and set the queryset attribute of the model choice field to one containing just the current user so the cleaning will enforce this against input spoofing.  (Deleting the field entirely from `form.fields` might work, but I haven't confirmed.) But that seems less clean to me.

Comment: Yes, there are solutions with one form, as @PeterDeGlopper. I might be biased, but I think that the two form approach is pretty elegant. Remember, your superuser form can subclass the other form, so there shouldn't be too much repetition.

Comment: I'm trying to think of an approach that will be simple to add to additional models that follow this pattern (ie have a user field that can only be set by staff). I'd love to be able to have a mixin that I could just enable for a view and have that pick the right model. That way the logic would be isolated to a single place rather than have it repeated across views as well as have repeated patterns with admin/non-admin forms. Even though one can easily inherit from the other and just use the exclude/include option.

Comment: I don't have a quick way to make my solution reusable as a mix in. Hope you manage to work it out.